# Postgresql: check if letter repeats in string

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
id   |  string
1    |  a,b,c,d,a,b
2    |  a,a,c,d,a,b
3    |  a,b,c,d
```

I want to check if letter 'a' repeats in string using regular expressions. How should i do that?

I try with

```
select * from table where string ~ 'a[^a]*'
```

but its not working.

Expected result:

```
id   |  string         | repeat_a
1    |  a,b,c,d,a,b    | t
2    |  a,a,c,d,a,b    | t
3    |  a,b,c,d        | f
```

Comment: What you want technically, is the `'(.*a){2}'` pattern, but you should think of a better db normalization, like a joining table instead of multiple values (separated by `,`) in the `string` column

Comment: +1 to what @pozs said. Normalize this design if possible, having non-sargable columns will cause inordinate amounts of pain. Plus, you can't set useful indexes on such a column.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to compare the input string against that string with all occurrences of the letter `'a'` removed.  A record which matches would then be characterized by the length of the replaced string being 2 or more characters shorter than the original input.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE char_length(string) > char_length(replace(string, 'a', '')) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your letter a is a value in a comma-separated list of values, then scanning for occurrences of the letter a may not be sufficient, as the letter may be contained in a value and not be "the" value. If that would be the case, you could do

```
SELECT string, val, count(*)
FROM table
JOIN LATERAL string_to_array(string, ',') val ON TRUE
WHERE val = 'a' -- remove this to see all the repeating values
GROUP BY val, string
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```